# Retrieving users included in services recursively

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with a hierarchical tree for the organization of a company.

[image]

Type 0: service | Type 1: user

```
* Global Service
    * Logisticians
      > Mike
      > George
    * Technicians
      * Drivers
        > Stef
        > John
      * Controllers
        > Alfred
```

I need to retrieve all users for a given service.

Examples:

```
In: 0   Out: 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
In: 1   Out: 5, 6
In: 2   Out: 7, 8, 9
In: 3   Out: 7, 8
In: 4   Out: 9
```

How can I query my table with a parameter (service ID) and getting all included users as a result ?

**Input: the ID of the service to query**

**Output: the IDs of the users included in this service**

Answer (score 0):

Frist create a data type to hold the table

```
create type testTypeM as table (Id int , Name varchar(30), ParentId int, Type bit)
```

Create a recursive function to get the  Hierarchy

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.TestFuncM (@ServiceId int,  @TableSrc  testTypeM READONLY)
Returns @rtnTable table (Id int , Name varchar(30), ParentId int, Type bit)
BEGIN

insert @rtnTable
SELECT * from @TableSrc WHERE Parentid = @ServiceId

IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @rtnTable) 
BEGIN
    insert @rtnTable 
    SELECT B.* FROM @rtnTable A cross Apply dbo.TestFuncM( A.Id,@TableSrc) B

END 
return 
END
```

Load the table into the table data type

```
DECLARE @TableSrc  testTypeM 
Insert @TableSrc (Id,Name, ParentId, Type) Values
 (0, 'Global Service', NULL, 0)
,(1, 'Logisticians', 0 ,0)
,(2, 'Technicians', 0 ,0)
,(3, 'Drivers', 2, 0)
,(4, 'Controllers', 2, 0)
,(5, 'Mike', 1, 1)
,(6, 'George',1,1)
,(7, 'Stef', 3, 1)
,(8, 'John', 3, 1)
,(9, 'Alfred', 4, 1)


-- In Prosduction 
--INSERT @TableSrc  
--SELECT * FROM Your table
```

Use as it

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.TestFuncM(0, @TableSrc) WHERE TYPE = 1;

Id          Name                           ParentId    Type
----------- ------------------------------ ----------- -----
5           Mike                           1           1
6           George                         1           1
7           Stef                           3           1
8           John                           3           1
9           Alfred                         4           1

SELECT * FROM dbo.TestFuncM(1, @TableSrc) WHERE TYPE = 1;
Id          Name                           ParentId    Type
----------- ------------------------------ ----------- -----
5           Mike                           1           1
6           George                         1           1

SELECT * FROM dbo.TestFuncM(2, @TableSrc) WHERE TYPE = 1;
Id          Name                           ParentId    Type
----------- ------------------------------ ----------- -----
7           Stef                           3           1
8           John                           3           1
9           Alfred                         4           1

SELECT * FROM dbo.TestFuncM(3, @TableSrc) WHERE TYPE = 1;
Id          Name                           ParentId    Type
----------- ------------------------------ ----------- -----
7           Stef                           3           1
8           John                           3           1

SELECT * FROM dbo.TestFuncM(4, @TableSrc) WHERE TYPE = 1;
Id          Name                           ParentId    Type
----------- ------------------------------ ----------- -----
9           Alfred                         4           1

SELECT * FROM dbo.TestFuncM(5, @TableSrc) WHERE TYPE = 1;
-- No Result`enter code here`
```

Comment: Your solution works, but I cannot introduce a user-defined function on my SQL SERVER. Is it possible to use only sql queries for that ? Thanks anyway.

Comment: you can try to use a physical table and create a looping to simulate the function behavior, after the lanch, I try to create something if nobody else answers it.

Comment: I created a new answer using a LOOP. It is easy to adapt to a procedure

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot create data type use the code below to create a procedure

The result is the same

```
DECLARE @YourTable table (Id int , Name varchar(30), ParentId int, Type bit)


Insert @YourTable values  
 (0, 'Global Service', NULL, 0)
,(1, 'Logisticians', 0 ,0)
,(2, 'Technicians', 0 ,0)
,(3, 'Drivers', 2, 0)
,(4, 'Controllers', 2, 0)
,(5, 'Mike', 1, 1)
,(6, 'George',1,1)
,(7, 'Stef', 3, 1)
,(8, 'John', 3, 1)
,(9, 'Alfred', 4, 1)


-- CREATE PROCEDURE ProcedureName 
DECLARE @ServiceId int -- Procedure Paramter


DECLARE @ExistsNextLevel bit = 1 
DECLARE @TableResult table (Id int , Name varchar(30), ParentId int, Type bit)

--- Remove this line in procedure 
SET @ServiceId = 1

INSERT @TableResult SELECT * FROM @YourTable WHERE Parentid = @ServiceId

WHILE (@ExistsNextLevel = 1) 
BEGIN   

    SET @ExistsNextLevel = 0 
    IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM @YourTable A WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @TableResult B WHERE A.Parentid = B.id)
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @TableResult c Where A.id = C.id) ) 
    BEGIN 
        SET @ExistsNextLevel = 1
    END

    INSERT @TableResult
    SELECT * FROM @YourTable A WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @TableResult B WHERE A.Parentid = B.id)
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @TableResult c Where A.id = C.id) 

END  


 SELECT * FROM @TableResult WHERE Type = 1
 -- GO

 -- EXEC ProcedureName  @ServiceId = 1
```